# выборка данных из бд в Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть таблица которая наполовину состоит из внешних ключей. 
[image: таблица с внешними ключами]
Как в Laravel через фасад DB построить запрос, чтобы вместо ключей выводилась полная инфа. Сам sql запрос несложный, а вот построить его в laravel не знаю как. 
Пример запроса:

```
SELECT `vidacha knig`.`nomer zapisi`, `Chitatel`.`familia` 
FROM `Chitatel`,`vidacha knig` 
WHERE `Chitatel`.`Nomer chitatelya` = `vidacha knig`.`nomer chitatelya`
```

Как подобный сделать в laravel? Может есть способ построить запрос на чистом sql

Comment: А вы используете модели на стороне laravel?

Comment: У меня проблема с миграциями в laravel. После миграций у меня mysql начинает выдавать кучу ошибок. Таблицы создаются, а работать с ними потом невозможно,  связи не создаются как со стороны mysql так и со стороны laravel. Если создать таблицы в ручную, тогда работают и связи бд в целом. Модели использую, но пока что надо разобраться со связями.Я ещё до конца не изучил проблему. Как решение одной из проблем - обновить mysql, но и с этим возникают трудности, так как мало опыта.

Comment: Попробуйте пройти курсы - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7FQEutaCiQ&index=1&list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme . Там есть субтитры русские. Первые уроки с заморочками рабочей среды можете пропустить. В качестве локального сервера под windows попробуйте xampp, laragon или openserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен `join`, вот пример заспроса для Laravel:

```
$query = DB::table('vidacha knig')
    ->join('Chitatel', 'vidacha knig.nomer chitatelya', '=', 'Chitatel.Nomer chitatelya')
    ->order_by('topic_time', 'desc')->get();
```

Дальше `$query` передавайте в представление.

Я правда не знаю, будет ли работать с пробелами (скорее всего нет). Я бы на вашем месте избавился от пробелов в названиях полей и таблиц.

[Документация по работе с базами данных Laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Answer (score 0):

Можете обернуть всё это в модели, т.е. Модель для записей, читателей, библиотекарей и книг, наладить связи (в вашем случае это **belongsTo**). 
И дальше работать через конструктор запросов ORM. Это во многих случаях удобнее, чем писать запросы.